# Pattern matching (like regex)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

This is a much more basic implementation of Regular Expressions ([Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)). Do note that core functionality is missing and the functions aren't completely fool-proof, but it does a good job of matching basic patterns. Also, filtering 'symmetric' patterns (like quotation marks "" or markdown bold **) is not possible.

That being said, here's the code:

```
"""
Module for quick and efficient pattern filtering.
Similar to Regular Expressions (https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html);
but with a goal of being easier to use. Note that lots of features that are available in re
are *not* available in this module. An example of supported operations:

- Filtering everything in parentheses () in a string
- Filtering every first occurrence of a word in parentheses () or square brackets []
- Tagging every verb in a string with angle brackets <> (given a list of verbs!)

An example of unsupported operations:

- Filtering email addresses from text 
- Retrieving text embedded in quotation marks '' 
- Complex text / lexical analysis
"""

class Crucial:
    """Basic interface for pattern matching and tagging. 
    You are recommended to use the Scope class for interacting with this interface.
    Contents:

    * _asymmetric(): Asymmetric pattern matching
    * _tag(): Asymmetric pattern tagging
    * _beautify(): Beautify results (append to list)
    """
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def _asymmetric(self, _raw, _start, _end, _filter_first):
        """Provides a backend interface for asymmetric pattern matching.
        Works for a 'raw' string, along with a single start / end character.
        Arguments:

        * _raw: String containing patterns to filter (e.g. 'spam [eggs]')
        * _start: Pattern start character (e.g. '[')
        * _end: Pattern end character  (e.g. ']')
        * _filter_first: Argument to filter only the first pattern found.
        """
        final = []
        temp, sort = [], []

        for pos, val in enumerate(_raw):
            if val == _start:
                temp.append([pos])
            elif val == _end:
                next = True
                for index in temp:
                    if _raw[index[0]] == _start:
                        next = False
                        # This avoids match collisions (missing end character)
                    if not next:
                        temp[temp.index(max(temp))].append(pos)
                        # Find the latest (max) pattern
                        sort.append(max(temp))
                        temp.pop(temp.index(max(temp)))

        for val in sorted(sort):
            final.append(_raw[val[0] + 1:val[-1]])
            if _filter_first:
                break
        return final

    def _tag(self, _raw, _tags, _seperator):
        """Provides a backend interface for asymmetric pattern tagging.
        Works for a 'raw' string, along with a tag dictionary and seperator character.
        Arguments:

        * _raw: String containing all words, not just those to be matched.
        * _tags: Dictionary containing key:value pairs like "spam":"[]" where every
                 "spam" will be enclosed by "[]" ("[spam]")
        * _seperator: Word seperator, commonly " " or ", " for a comma-seperated list.
        """

        final = ""

        for val in _raw.split(_seperator):
            if val not in _tags:
                final += val + _seperator 
            else:
                final += _tags[val][0] + val + _tags[val][1]
                final += _seperator

        return final

    def _beautify(self, _filtered, _allow_nested):
        """Beautify filtered patterns by appending them to a list.
        Works for 'filtered' dictionaries.
        Arguments:

        * _filtered: Dictionary with results matched by start / end character
        * _allow_nested: Boolean, if True, all results will be returned in a list or printed.
                     Else, only 'pure' results (results containing no nested patterns), are returned.
        """

        def is_nested(frm):
            # Check if a frame is pure, treating it as 'raw'
            result = Scope().auto(frm)
            for pattern_ in result:
                for frame_ in result[pattern_]:
                    if len(frame_) > 0:
                        return True
            return False 

        final = []
        for pattern in _filtered:
            for frame in _filtered[pattern]:
                if not _allow_nested:
                    if not is_nested(frame):
                        final.append(frame)
                        continue
                    continue
                final.append(frame)
        return final       


class Scope:
    """Main frontend interface for pattern matching / tagging.
    Contents:

    * _err(): Function for constructing error messages
    * match(): Allows asymmetric pattern matching
    * tag(): Tag specific words in a raw string
    * auto(): Automatically match patterns
    * beautify(): Wrapper for backend _beautify()
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.RED = "\033[91m"
        self.GRN = "\033[92m"
        self.YLW = "\033[93m"
        self.WHT = "\033[00m"

    def _err(self, message):
        """Print errors to the screen."""
        print("{}{}{}".format(self.RED, message, self.WHT))

    def match(self, raw, *args, filter_first=False):
        """Match patterns based on asymmetric characters.
        match() will always return a dictionary with key:value pairs like
        pattern_start + pattern_end : [returned, items, seperatd, with, commas].
        Arguments:

        * raw: A raw string to be inspected for patterns
        * *args: Any amount of arguments (patterns), in the form of
                 "<>", "[]", "()". For example: match("spam [eggs]", "[]")
        * filter_frames: Optional argument to filter only the first frame of each pattern.
        """
        final = {}

        for arg in args:
            # arg represents a pattern.
            start = arg[0]
            end = arg[1]

            collision = (start + end in args and end + start in args)
            if collision:
                self._err("Collision: {}{} / {}{}".format(start, end, end, start))
                return

            final[start + end] = Crucial()._asymmetric(raw, start, end, filter_first)
        return final

    def tag(self, raw, tags, seperator=" "):
        """Encapsulate words based on a 'tags' enum.
        Arguments:

        * raw: A raw string containing words to be tagged
        * tags: Dictionary containing key:value pairs like "spam":"[]".
                Each "spam" in raw will be surrounded by "[" ... "]".
        * seperator: Optional argument for seperating words (string.split()).
                     Defaults to a single space " ".
        """
        return Crucial()._tag(raw, tags, seperator)

    def auto(self, raw):
        """Automatically match frames in a string, based on common patterns.
        auto() will always return a dictionary with key:value pairs like
        pattern_start + pattern_end : [returned, items, seperatd, with, commas].
        Arguments:

        * raw: A raw string to be inspected for patterns
        """
        final = {}
        temp = []

        for pattern in ["()", "[]", "<>", "{}"]:
            if pattern[0] in raw and pattern[1] in raw:
                result = Scope().match(raw, pattern)
                for pattern_ in result:
                    final[pattern_] = result[pattern_]

        return final

    def beautify(self, filtered, allow_nested=True):
        """Beautify matched patterns.
        Arguments:

        * filtered: Dictionary containing filtered patterns
        * allow_nested: If set to True, nested patterns are allowed.
                        Else, only 'pure' patterns are used.
        """
        return Crucial()._beautify(filtered, allow_nested)
```

And here's some examples:

```
import scope
scope = scope.Scope()

easy = "The (quick) (grey) [fox] jumps over the (lazy) (white) [dog]"

hard = """
This is (level 0 and (this is level 1. (Level 2 is especially (interesting) for pattern matching!) 
[this is additional information, although it doesn't help you understand what is going on.))
"""

print(scope.match(easy, "()"))
# Match adjectives

print(scope.match(easy, "[]"))
# Match nouns

print(scope.auto(easy))
# Match both nouns and adjectives

print(scope.beautify(scope.auto(easy)))
# Convert the results to a list and print it

print(scope.beautify(scope.auto(hard), allow_nested=False)) 
# Print only 'pure' patterns

print(scope.tag(hard, {"is":"<>"}))
# Tag all verbs 'is' with angle brackets
# etc.
```

I would appreciate any advice / critisism regarding coding conventions or style, performance, usability, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some high-level thoughts and notes:

- I think you don't really need to have leading underscores in the method argument names
- there is a *typo*: `_seperator` -> `_separator` (the typo is consistent in both the code and the docstrings)
- you can *unpack* `arg` in a loop, replacing:

  ```
  for arg in args:
      # arg represents a pattern.
      start = arg[0]
      end = arg[1]
  ```

  with:

  ```
  for start, end in args:
  ```
- [*shadowing built-in function*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9109333/771848): `next` is shadowed in the `_asymmetric()` method
- `temp` variable is unused inside the `auto()` method
- I would probably move the "color"-constants from being instance variables into the scope of the module or to a scope of a class itself:

  ```
  class Scope:
      RED = "\033[91m"
      GRN = "\033[92m"
      YLW = "\033[93m"
      WHT = "\033[00m"
  ```

Overall, my feeling was that *you actually don't need classes here* - most of the methods you use can actually be static and you don't have instance variables - there is basically no "state" shared across the methods:

- [Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)

Comment: Does this mean simply using ```@staticmethod``` would be good enough, or should I abandon the use of classes altogether (and if so, how can I keep the code well organized?)?

Comment: @Coal_ I am also struggling with the best and the clearest indication of what is better - have a class that acts as a bucket - used to organize and group related things together, or to have a module/package for the same purpose. There is [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472615/use-classes-or-modules-to-group-static-like-methods) eventually closed as opinion-based; also see [this topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184879/in-python-is-it-considered-better-to-define-a-module-with-functions-or-a-module). I tend to think of a module for your use-case.